# existing database using with web api 2 default test project

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

I have created database with following tables

[image]

I'm trying to use this table structure with default test project in web api 2.

Once I run this through POSTMAN rest client , I'm getting following exception

[image]

is this possible to do, can I use existing identity table structure that mapped relationships with other tables

Comment: Can you see your exception in that image you have posted?

Comment: yes its saying `An error occured while updating the entities, see the inner exception for details`

Comment: so where is the inner exception?

Comment: how can I see it, I can show only in postman above pic details only, Im new to web api, please advise

Comment: Use the debugger. This has nothing to do with Web API. Put a try catch in your datacontext's method or web api method and then see what the inner exception is

Comment: Coding Yoshi pointed out right here, see the inner exception https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HQ1x.png

Comment: which exception do you give? (the DETAIL) .. is for FK?